# python for loop to get the factorial of a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, range

```
# factorial program
n = int(input())
fact = 1
for i in range(n,1,-1):      #line4 #  this line print the range in reverce
    fact = fact*i
print(fact)
```

some explain the line4. how is the for loop printing the n in reverse?

Comment: The third `range` arg is the "step" and is negative. BTW, for computing a factorial a reverse order is not nedded at all.

Comment: The loop doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3 main parameters of the `range()` function are start, stop and step. If you start at `n` to stop on 1 and decrease the index variable by 1 unit every time the loop executes, it will loop the values in reverse order.

For example:

```
n=10
for i in range(n,1,-1):
    print(i)
```

This loop will start at `i=10`, as you can see from the step value, it will decrease its value by 1 until reach the stop value *(exclusive)*, in this case, 1 too. So the output will be:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
```